# Is it possible to conditionally set php_value in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to set `php_value` (`error_log`) based on the host server. If it is a local server:

```
php_value error_log  ./PHP_errors.log
```

and if it is the remote server:

```
php_value error_log  /home/user_id/public_html/PHP_errors.log
```

I tried using

```
SetEnvIf Host "localhost"
php_value error_log  ./PHP_errors.log
```

but it returns error. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can set this conditionally from within .htaccess, but there's an easy workaround. Make an auto-prepended PHP script and set the values from there, using PHP's ini_set function.